# remove a line from file which only contains new line

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read a file and want to return the data as a list of tuple. at the end of the file a line which only contain a new line i want to remove that line.

i have tried python function like strip(),replace().these removes the "\n" from the end of the line except the last line.

data.txt

```
     X          Class
   1  15.79311545   YES
   2  10.95644178   YES
   3  27.77413952   NO
   4  18.41013616   NO
   5  18.74485271   NO
   6  22.44869209   NO
   7  18.09242441   NO
   8  15.24850737   NO
   9  11.21480959   YES
   10 13.195037 NO
   11
```

function.py

```
 def readAllData(file_name):
   with open(file_name) as file:
    for line in file:
        filelist = [line.replace('\n','') for line in file]
        # filelist = line.splitlines()
        t = [tuple(map(str, i.split('\t'))) for i in filelist]
        print(t)
    return t
```

Comment: are the numbers (1, 2, 3...) part of the file?

Comment: no. these are line numbers.

Comment: If the file is not too large, you could use `for line in file.read().strip()` to get rid of the last newline characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one note first, this…

```
for line in file:
    filelist = [line.replace('\n','') for line in file]
```

…is almost certainly not what you want. You only want a single `for` loop. Get rid of the other one.

```
filelist = [line.replace('\n', '') for line in file]
```

Now, to skip over a line that's nothing but whitespace:

```
filelist = [line.replace('\n', '') for line in file if line.strip()]
```

With this guard in place, if `line.strip()` returns `False` (or anything `False`-like, including the empty string), the list comprehension will leave it out.

Comment: What?  why not just `line.strip()` instead of `[line.replace('\n', '')`

Comment: @StephenRauch No reason except that I try not to change the asker's code any more than necessary. For all I know they may want leading tabs preserved. (Probably not, but…)

Comment: @StephenRauch Thank you so much. it worked! Actually I am learning python only for few days. my knowledge is almost nothing on python. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `iter` function to read until a standalone newline:

```
def readAllData(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        return [tuple(line.split()) for line in iter(file.readline, '\n')]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply ignore these lines as you encounter them:

```
def readAllData(file_name):
    lst = []
    with open(file_name) as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.startswith('\n'):
                continue
            t = tuple(line.split())
            print(t)
            lst.append(t)
        return lst
```

Comment: Why `map(str...` on a `str`?

Comment: Note that your code never defines `filelist`. And the `t` you return at the end will only have the final line.

Comment: Your indenting is broken

Comment: @Draconis fixed it now

Comment: @anand_v.singh You still never define the `filelist` variable.

Comment: @StephenRauch I don't know the indenting looks fixed when I try to edit, maybe I don't understand the answering interface correctly.

Comment: @Draconis I think you are talking about `lst` defined at line 2, if that's it, I will rename it, or am I missing something else?

Comment: @anand_v.singh Try running your code. You use `filelist` in the list comprehension, but got rid of the line that actually creates that variable.

Comment: @Draconis Sorry I see it now.